# Why am I getting Invalid Token from AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

Startup.cs :

```
...
services.AddIdentityCore<CustomerEntity>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ClientContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
   .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<CustomerEntity>>();
...
```

CustomerService.cs

```
public async Task<string> RequestPasswordResetTokenAsync(Guid programId, string email)
{
  Mandate.NotEmpty(programId, nameof(programId));
  Mandate.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(email, nameof(email));

  var customerEntity = await CustomerQuery(programId, true).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == email);

  if (customerEntity == null)
    throw new CustomerDoesNotExistException();

  return await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(customerEntity);
}
...

public async Task ResetPasswordAsync(Guid programId, string email, string token, string newPassword)
{
    Mandate.NotEmpty(programId, nameof(programId));
    Mandate.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(email, nameof(email));
    Mandate.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(token, nameof(token));
    Mandate.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(newPassword, nameof(newPassword));

    CheckPassword(email, newPassword);

    var user = await CustomerQuery(programId, true).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == email);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new CustomerDoesNotExistException();
    }

    var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        // Always fails from a link.  
        throw new InvalidPasswordException(newPassword);
    }
}
```

I have verified that the Tokens are encoded and decoded correctly, or at least they match on the RequestReset and on the parameter to the ResetPassword. I've tried getting resetting right after getting the token ant that works, but it doesn't work when 'coming back in'.  We're in the process of upgrading from 3.1 to 6 so I'm sure there's something that changed, but I can't tell what.  Our Services project is still on 3.1, but our web projects are on 6 if that matters.  I've seen one suggestion that _userManager might be 2 different instances.  I tried changing the CustomerService (which uses UserManager) from InstancePerLifetimeScope to a couple of different types, but that broke things or didn't change anything.  This upgrade has been a nightmare. I see a lot of the same suggestions, and I feel like I've tried them, so I'm hoping someone has something new for me to try.  Thanks.

Edit to say I've looked at '+' signes in the Token, and they are being encoded/decoded correctly.